# SCJP Mock Question: How many objects are eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, scjp

I was asked a question (on this site http://scjptest.com/): How many objects are eligible for garbage collection in this code sample at the line // some code goes here?

```
class A {
    private B b;
    public A() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B {
    private A a;
    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A aa = new A();
        aa = null;
        // some code goes here
    }
}
```

The correct answer is: "The objects referenced by a and b are eligible for garbage collection.". But why? they contain loop references to each other, they are accessible to each other.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> they contain loop references to each other, they are accessible to each other.

Yes, but they aren't anymore accessible from anywhere else, so they can't be seen and used in the program anymore.

Early GCs had problems collecting such self-referencing object groups but with modern generational collectors it is a solved problem.

In brief, the GC can walk through the web of references from the known static and stack objects, and either

- copy all objects found to a new memory pool, automatically leaving behind any "dead" objects (this is the "young generation" strategy), or
- mark all objects found, so that once the whole web of references is walked traversed, it can delete all unmarked objects (this is the "old/tenured generation" strategy).

Answer (score 2):

That's because java has a *generational garbage collector* so it can collect groups of objects that have references between them, but not from the *main* application.

There is a more in depth explanation [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11253/).

As far as I remember (and I might be wrong) this wasn't the case with old versions of java (such as java 1.2), in which the cyclic dependencies had to be cleared manually in order for the GC to collect them.

Comment: I don't think the fact that gc is generational is the issue here; that's just an implementation detail for certain JVMs. It's the fact that there are no references from the root set, so the objects are eligible for gc.

Comment: @Simon: old GCs only garbage collected an object only if the reference count was 0. So if you had 2 objects with references to each other, they would never be GCed. This is luckily ancient history nowadays.

Comment: The detection of cycles is unrelated to the kind of GC used, the only exception being refcounting (alone; there are several popular language implementations that use refcounting but have a simple GC for cycles), and it's arguable if it counts as GC precisely because of this limitation. So unless early Java didn't do garbage collection properly, your memory is wrong.

Comment: @Delnan I'll leave the exercise of going through the java 1.1 / 1.2 docs to you then :)

Comment: Well, http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/thinkinginjava/abitaboutgarbagecollection.html is "copyright 1998, 1999, 2000" and says that "Reference counting is commonly used to explain one kind of garbage collection but it doesn't seem to be used in any JVM implementations." I'll look if I can find anything else, but I consider it impropable and would appreciate a reference.

Comment: Also found http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10283/, which states that "Early JDKs used a single-threaded mark-sweep or mark-sweep-compact collector." and goes on to describe the GC used in 1.2, so I assume it says even the very early JVMs used mark-and-sweep. Seriously, `[citation needed]`. (It may be possible that you're thinking of cycles with finalizers, which can indeed prevent GC; but the problems that cause this aren't solvable by *any* GC algorithm)

Comment: I got that from my own experience, in which I had to manually unlink objects for them to be collected (I think this was with java 1.2). The objects formed a very large graph and the JVM wouldn't GC those objects unless I cleared the references. (I had to transverse the graph clearing the references). I wouldn't be surprised if the java documentation says something and the real implementation behaved differently in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

The GC can remove so called "island of objects" if none of the objects from that "island" (or group) cannot be accessed from **any** thread !

In your example you create an object A that has link to another object B. But the object B is not "reference-able" by anyone expect A. You can view the two objects as an island.
When A is gone, GC will be smart enough to figure out that B cannot be referenced by any other thread and thus you will have 2 objects being removed.

Comment: +1 for that definition: the one that's on the SCJP6 book of Sierra & Bates

Answer (score 1):

let's draw the scenario to understand clearly.

```
A a = new A()
```

> a ------------this points to object------------> A() "1st object"

in A()'s constructor you instantiate an instance of B() "2nd object"

inside the class B instance is just pointing to the A() above, so no new object created.
At the point you assigned a null value to "a" variable, no reference will be pointing to A() object. Now you have 2 objects eligible for GC. Don't worry about the class referencing each other, just focus on the declaration inside your main method.